# Render 2D text in Autodesk Forge without aliasing or blurring

Tags: 2d, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Turns out I’m working with the Autodesk Forge viewer and Three.js, trying to render 2D text that can be interacted with (specifically select, rotate, and move).

To do this I am working with meshes (using MeshBasicMaterial, Mesh and TextGeometry) but it turns out that the text does not look perfectly sharp, it presents aliasing and I found that according to the API reference, the antialiasing is not applicable to 2d.

Here are some examples of the problem, as you can see, the more I move away from the plane, the worse the text looks (and even up close it doesn't look perfect):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried to make a test representing the text with a Sprite (despite the fact that it would mean having to change the entire implementation already made with meshes of other functionalities) but apart from the fact that I cannot see it, I have seen example images and they do not appear either well: aliasing is visible from a distance and it looks really blurry up close. Here some examples:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to correct this problem or is this the most I can get in 2D? I've tried searching for information on this but can't find anything helpful. And what has puzzled me the most has been realizing that antialiasing was not applicable in the case of 2d, like making it clear that nothing can be done to fix it.

I would be very grateful if you could solve my doubts, thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier alternative, is to just use a higher pixel ratio for the renderer...

```
window.devicePixelRatio=2;  
viewer.resize();
```

For example, using the custom geometry text, from Joao's demo, you can see the same aliasing issue at DPR=0.5 and DPR=1.0 ...

https://joaomartins-forge.github.io/textgeometry-sample/

But when I set the DPR=2.0, the text looks clean.  The trade off is rendering performance, but your 2D drawings may be simple enough that it won't matter.  You can use a 'mouse up' camera settle trick, to switch between DPR of 1 and 2, if you want a better UX experience.

[image: DPR of .5, 1 and 2]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved our problem!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this aliasing issue for 2D (and 3D text).

The way I would recommend for your use case, is to use DIV elements (THREE.CSS3DRenderer), instead of text converted into three.js tessellated triangle geometry, as shown in this blog post:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-do-you-add-labels-forge-viewer

You can find out more information about THREE.CSS3DRenderer here:
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS3DRenderer

and an Example here: https://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_periodictable

Using CSS3DRenderer instead of CSS2DRenderer, means you will get the correct scaling (and rotation) of the div element as you zoom into your 2D drawing and the mathematics inside the calculation for the matrix transform has less edge-cases.

Once you are using DIV elements for your text, you will notice that the text is sharper and has no aliasing issues.  That's because it is not being rasterized by the webGL pipeline, but by the SKIA library used by chrome/firefox/opera/etc for rasterizing text.

There is one final option, that uses signed-distance fields, but it's probably overkill for what you need.

Let me know if you want some example code.